# importing functions from .cpp file into python

Tags: python, c++, cython, boost-python

Let me start with a disclaimer that i'm putting this question after lot of research and not finding any direct and step by step example.

Have gone through Cython , SWIG, Boostpython documentation but couldn't get a step by step process and so posting here -

I have a .cpp & .h file with couple of mathematical functions defined.I want to call them in a python (.py) code file.

How do i integrate?Which is the best and neatest way to go about it. Please illustrate

Comment: Most people would consider [this](http://www.swig.org/tutorial.html) and [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/index.html) to be step by step guides to SWIG and Boost.Python, respectively. What exactly do you need that these don't provide?

Comment: This [post][1] seems to answer your question by using library ctypes.

[1]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145270/calling-c-c-from-python

Comment: "Best" is subjective. For simple code, just make sure your cpp code has a C interface (extern "C") and use ctypes. Just look at the official docs for ctypes.

Comment: Please, add an example of one function of yours, it will become easier to propose how to do it...

Comment: Trying to do it via Cython

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since i eventually solved it using some of the help provided here and research , let me post the answer.

I did the import of CPP function via Python using Cython.

Cython wraps the Python code with CPP file and compiles the two. The outcome is a Python module (name of the module can be specified in setup.py file ) and the module can be called as usual.

The issue i was facing was calling a CPP function from Python.So here are my tips for working it out

1. Define your function in C++ Header and  CPP file.
2. Using cdef , define the function in Python script in the beginning where you import modules define other variables.This definition is similar to C++ header file definition
3. While pasing arguments and arrays to the function call from python , ensure all variables and arrays are type casted as CPP.
4. For arrays, it is a bit tricky. E.G. a double array in Python can be type casted using `array.array(array_to_cast)`. In the following example, we cast the python array, `dev`, into the c++ array, `dev_arr`. *Note that `dev` is an array of type double in python, hence the first parameter input to `array.array()` is 'd'*.

```
cdef array.array dev_arr = array.array('d',dev)
```

While passing the `dev_arr` array to your main CPP function, you have to specify this array :*data.as_doubles*

```
fn_response = cpp_fn_call(stddev_arr.data.as_doubles,...)
```

Rest will work smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

See [this part](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/clibraries.html) of the Cython documentation; it takes you step-by-step through interfacing with a C library.